# Yii session timeout not working

Tags: session, yii

same as title, in my config:

```
'session' => array(
   'class'=>'CHttpSession',
   'timeout'=> 1200,
   'autoStart'=>true,
),
```

in my code:

```
$ssKey = 'MY_SS_KEY';

if (isset(Yii::app()->session[$ssKey])) {
   $this->jobWithSession();
} else {
   $this->jobWithNotSession();
   Yii::app()->session[$ssKey] = 'ok';
}
```

first time, it call function jobWithNotSession(), but after over 1200s (20 minute), it still call function jobWithNotSession, what's wrong? somebody can help me?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make Yii session timeout to work, you should do the following:

In protected/config/main.php:

```
'components'=>array(
               'session' => array(
                  'class' => 'CDbHttpSession', //Set class to CDbHttpSession
                  'timeout' => 1800, //Any time, in seconds
                ),
              ),
```

1800 is the time, in seconds, during which your time session will be active.
It is algo important to set the class to CDbHttpSession.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong functionality here. The session timeout is only applicable when the php garbage collector is getting called, which is far from every page-view. It has something to do with the [`gc_probability`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability)-setting. So that's not what you want to use. As long as it doesn't run, the session still exists (even though expired) and the user remains logged in.

What you do want is to "remove" the autoLogin cookie, which you can do by controlling the duration of it.
So basically what you need to change is the `duration` parameter of the [`CWebUser::login()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail)-function.